# How can I use MATLAB in atom?

Tags: path, matlab, atom-editor

I want to be able to run matlab scripts in atom using the `script` paclage.

When I do so, I get the following error.

```
MATLAB - Coins_Riddler.m:23
Unable to run

matlab
Did you start Atom from the command line?



 atom .
```

It looks like matlab isn't in my path.  A lot of forums say to include `/Applications/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin` in my path, but even doing that doesn't work.  Calling `matlab` from the terminal gets an `command not found` error, and atom still won't read my matlab script.

Comment: I don't have matlab installed but can you confirm if the Matlab executable is in that path? If you go under Terminal and go into that path (/Applications/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin) - does this path existed? Is the `matlab` executable is in there?

Answer (score 1):

The script package has a grammars.coffee file:

`/.atom/packages/script/lib/grammars.coffee`

Search for the MATLAB section and change command from "matlab" to 
"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/matlab"

`command: "/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab"`

Answer (score 0):

The plugin has been updated and there is no `grammars.coffee` any more.
You should modify `index.coffee` in `/.atom/packages/script/lib/grammars/`
changing it to:

```
command: '/Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app/bin/matlab'
```